# How do I display different divs based on month and day?

Tags: php

I am trying to make my site show different a different div during February 15th and November 15 than the rest of the year.  Would someone show me what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php
        $today = date('m-d');
        $enrollDate = date('m-d', strtotime($today));
        $enrollBegin = date('m-d', strtotime('02-15'));
        $enrollEnd = date('m-d', strtotime('11-15'));
        if (($enrollDate >= $enrollBegin) && ($enrollDate <= $enrollEnd)) { ?>
        <div  id="qualifybox">Show this div from Feb 15 to Nov 15</div>

        <?php } else { ?>

        <div  id="gobox">Show this div from Nov 15 to Feb 15</div>
        <?php } ?>
```

Thanks!

I've tried changing the date to test my else div--but it will not show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditionals are in reversed order :

```
 if (($enrollDate <= $enrollEnd) && ($enrollDate >= $enrollBegin)) { ?>
```

Comment: ...and for readabilty: first enrollBegin, then enrollEnd. :-) <? if (($enrollDate >= $enrollBegin) && ($enrollDate <= $enrollEnd)) { ?>

Comment: I made the changes, but i can't get it to display my else statement.

Comment: I made the test myself locally, based on your code. This is the only line to change, and it works...

Comment: thanks for your help.  I couldn't get that to work for some reason, but I got rid of strtotime and now it works. '<?php
            $today = date('m-d');
            $enrollBegin = '02-15';
            $enrollEnd = '11-15';
            if (($today >= $enrollBegin) && ($today <= $enrollEnd)) { ?>'

Comment: FYI, I prefer to use date with mktime, as shown on the php website. Take a look at the examples : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php